# Different Result When Using RecyclerView in Emulator with API23 and API19

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

Why do I get different results on both my emulator? If using an emulator **API23** the retrieval of data to the server does not appear on RecyclerView.
But otherwise if I use the emulator with **API19** then the results come out as I wanted.

Whether there should be added in my code specifically for this API23? Since I only use the INTERNET permission (already added to AndroidManifest) for an example of this application.

Please see this result

[image: When I using emulator with API23]

As you can see above, if I use the API emulator 23 no error, the data simply do not appear on the screen emulator. I have tried on a real device and the result is the same

If I use emulator API19
[image]

But when I use emulator API19 the data appears on the screen as well

I have tried on a real device and the results data to be shown out well on this API19.

What should I do? Are there any special treatment for API 23? Up here I am at a loss to find a solution. Please help

**MainActivity**

```
package com.transvision.bertho.transvisiondashboardapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.onesignal.OneSignal;

import cn.pedant.SweetAlert.SweetAlertDialog;
import page.DefaultFragment;
import page.HomeFragment;
import page.ProfileFragment;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        OneSignal.startInit(this).init();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        Fragment fragment = null;
        fragment = new DefaultFragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.root, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        new SweetAlertDialog(this, SweetAlertDialog.SUCCESS_TYPE)
                .setTitleText("Good job!")
                .setContentText("You clicked the button!")
                .show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        Fragment fragment = null;
        String title = getString(R.string.app_name);

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            title = "Home";
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
            fragment = new ProfileFragment();
            title = "Profile";
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.root, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }


    public void showToast(String output){
        Toast.makeText(this.getBaseContext(), output, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

**HomeFragment**

```
package page;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.transvision.bertho.transvisiondashboardapp.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import adapter.ChannelAdapter;
import butterknife.Bind;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import model.Channel;
import model.ChannelResponse;
import rest.ApiClient;
import rest.ApiInterface;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;


public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

    @Bind(R.id.movies_recycler_view) RecyclerView recyclerView;
    @Bind(R.id.swipe_layout) SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;

    private static final String TAG = HomeFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    private ChannelAdapter adapter;
    List<Channel> listChannel;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView);

        listChannel = new ArrayList<>();

        setUpSwipeLayout();
        setUpAdapter();
        setUpRecyclerview();

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                load();
            }
        }, 500);

        return rootView;
    }

    protected void setUpSwipeLayout()
    {
        swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.colorPrimary, R.color.colorAccent);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
    }

    private void setUpAdapter(){
        if(adapter == null){
            adapter = new ChannelAdapter(listChannel, R.layout.list_channel, getActivity());
        }
    }

    private void setUpRecyclerview(){
        recyclerView.clearOnScrollListeners();
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void load(){
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
        ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getChannel().create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<ChannelResponse> call = apiService.getItems();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<ChannelResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ChannelResponse> call, Response<ChannelResponse> response) {

                listChannel = response.body().getItems();
                adapter = new ChannelAdapter(listChannel, R.layout.list_channel, getActivity());
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                recyclerView.clearOnScrollListeners();
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                Log.e(TAG, "CONNECTION SUCCESS");
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ChannelResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
                showToast("CONNECTION ERROR");
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }

    public void showToast(String output){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), output, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        load();
    }
}
```

**ChannelAdapter**

```
package adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.transvision.bertho.transvisiondashboardapp.R;

import java.util.List;

import model.Channel;


public class ChannelAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChannelAdapter.ChannelViewHolder> {

    private List<Channel> channels;
    private int rowLayout;
    private Context context;

    public ChannelAdapter(List<Channel> channels, int rowLayout, Context context) {
        this.channels = channels;
        this.rowLayout = rowLayout;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public static class ChannelViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        LinearLayout moviesLayout;

        TextView name;
        TextView description;
        TextView definition;

        public ChannelViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            moviesLayout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.movies_layout);
            name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
            definition = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);
            description = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.description);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ChannelViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(rowLayout, parent, false);
        return new ChannelViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ChannelViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.name.setText(channels.get(position).getName());
        holder.definition.setText(channels.get(position).getDefinition());
        holder.description.setText(channels.get(position).getDescription());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return channels.size();
    }


}
```

**Channel**

```
package model;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Channel {

    @SerializedName("id")
    private String id;
    @SerializedName("name")
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("code")
    private String code;
    @SerializedName("description")
    private String description;
    @SerializedName("number")
    private Integer number;
    @SerializedName("definition")
    private String definition;
    @SerializedName("paket")
    private String paket;
    @SerializedName("logo")
    private String logo;

    public Channel(String id, String name, String code, String description, Integer number, String definition, String paket, String logo) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.code = code;
        this.description = description;
        this.number = number;
        this.definition = definition;
        this.paket = paket;
        this.logo = logo;
    }

    public String getID() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setID(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Integer getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(Integer number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getDefinition() {
        return definition;
    }

    public void setDefinition(String definition) {
        this.definition = definition;
    }

    public String getPaket() {
        return paket;
    }

    public void setPaket(String paket) {
        this.paket = paket;
    }

    public String getLogo() {
        return logo;
    }

    public void setLogo(String logo) {
        this.logo = logo;
    }

}
```

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: Hi @PankajKumar check my update above

Comment: Any idea @PankajKumar ?